# id autoincrement while load data infile

Tags: php, mysql

If my question is not correct please edit it instead of downvoting I just got the warning.please somebody edit it

I have a table with 4 fields(id, startip, endip, countrycode) and my csvfile has (startip, endip, countryip), when I run the following code. id column of a table is filled with startip of csv file and startip column of table is filled endip of csvfile etc. I want the id column of table be autoincremented.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'info.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_countryip FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would have included the id field in your SQL insert query. check it. and also set your id to autoincrement. Besides the code what you provided is really insufficient to provide an answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply, my table has id field which is set to autoincrement

Comment: If you need answer than you should provide sufficient code.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the id as Autoincrement in your database, I asume you are using MySql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: thanks for your reply, my table has id field which is set to autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `id`  AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
```

Then just upload the csv as normal ( theer should be no ID column in the csv file)

Comment: thanks for your reply, my table has id field which is set to autoincrement